# Does the default assignment operator call operator= on all members?

Tags: c++, class, copy-constructor, assignment-operator

And similarly, does the default copy constructor call the copy constructor on all members?  For example, if a class has a non-POD member like so:

```
class A
{
    std::string str;
};
```

...will the default compiler-generated copy constructor and assignment operator work correctly?  Will they call the string's copy constructor and `operator=` or will they just make a bitwise copy of member variable `str`?

In other words, does having a `std::string` member mean this class needs a user-implemented copy constructor and assignment operator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the compiler-generated one will work correctly.

However, if you implement your own and leave them empty, it won't.

If you're not managing memory and all your members provide correct copying/assignment/destruction, you don't need (and shouldn't) implement your own copy constructor/destructor/assignment operator.

> In other words, does having a std::string member mean this class needs a user-implemented copy constructor and assignment operator?

No, the compiler-generated ones will work perfectly.

Comment: "Yes, the compiler-generated one will work correctly." - even for classes with const members?

Comment: @spin_eight well then a copy or assignment wouldn't even compile.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Actually, a copy will compile. The assignment won't obviously.